# Record iphone System or audio player sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am developing an app module in which i am doing audio recording with also video recording.

but i want to record only device intrnal playing sound , not the device external voice.

If any advise or suggestion to got it..!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you can use buffers to write them into a file Audio units or Audio Queues without using mic